# How to create date object from next day of week, hh:mm and utc offset

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have these 4 input values.

- Day of week: integer 0-6 (0: Sunday, 1: Monday, ... 6: Saturday)
- Hours: integer 0-24
- Minutes: integer 0-60
- UTC offset: integer -12 - 14

With above input values, I want to create date object.
Day of week can be either of next week or this week according to current time.
Eg.
Lets assume current time is 10:00 Mon 2021.
And day of week is 1 (Monday) and Hours is 12 then this is today.
Other case, if hours is less than 10 then it would be next Monday(next week).
I have tried moment and date in javascript but I got stuck here.
Please advise me to make this createDate function

```
var createDate(var dow, var hh, var mm, var utc){
  //return date object
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you have tried, but just create the date object in moment or vanilla JS and compare it with the current day, if it is lesser, add 7 days. Relational operations and date arithmetic would be fairly easy with moment

Answer (score 1):

For the date part consider the following:

```
function createDate(dow, hh, mm, utc) {
  const date_today = moment();
  const dow_today = date_today.day();

  var days_dif = dow - dow_today;

  if (days_dif < 0) {
    console.log(moment().add(7, 'd').format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
  } else {
    console.log(moment().add(days_dif, 'd').format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
  }
}
```

You'll have to add more `if` statements for hours and minutes if `date_dif` is equal to 0, otherwise just add hours and minutes to the date in the `else` statement.

Comment: thanks. but i am wondering if this function is considering utc. eg if utc = 5 this means gmt+5:00. and I want to set date with that timezone.

Comment: The [docs](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) say `If you wish to interact with the date as a UTC date, use moment.utc. This results in a date with a utc offset of +0:00.`. Just compare it with the `utc` parameter and apply the necessary operations.

Comment: @development-ninja—you can't "set" a date with a particular timezone. While a particular offset may correlate with standard timezones (e.g. +5 is military timezone E or echo), there may be multiple named timezones that have the same offset, including some with standard time and others with daylight saving time. So specifying a particular offset is easy, mapping an offset to particular timezone isn't, and is frequently ambiguous.